# I need to find and insert a value

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a script that needs to find a numerical values or digits in a text file and replace it with input from my keyboard.

I have searched on the internet and just can't find the correct way to do it.

The text file contains the following:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\userapp\fundays\jv10_80cl1\test
```

i need to change the "80cl1" part to new values eg: 80cl1 changes to 84cl3

```
:begin1
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P E= new value 1: 

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (install.txt) do findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$"
    echo "%%a"

SET /P R= New value 2: 

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (install.txt) do findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$"
    echo "%%a"
```

So, the script needs to find those values and change it via keyboard input.

Comment: Why do you need keyboard input? Can't you just do a sed on the file and specify the replacement string immediately?

Comment: you cannot edit just 1 item in a text file using batch, you have to basically rewrite all lines back to the file.

Comment: Here are the results of a Stack Overflow search with [\[batch-file\] replace](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+replace) and one more with [\[batch-file\] replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+replace+string) and last with [\[batch-file\] JREPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+JREPL.BAT). I don't believe it that you have really searched enough for a solution taking into account that there are thousands of working solutions posted on Stack Overflow which are very easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help. You can change the `set /p` to not promp and just give it a value, either way will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set inputfile=install.txt
set /p "_strfind=Enter value to search?"
set /p "_strinsert=Replacement value?"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%inputfile%"') do (
    set "str=%%a"
    set "str=!str:%_strfind%=%_strinsert%!"
    set "str=!str:*]=!"
    >>%inputfile% echo(!str!
)
```

If you do not want to be pompted, just set the values before hand:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set inputfile=install.txt
set "_strfind=80cl1"
set "_strinsert=84cl3"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%inputfile%"') do (
    set "str=%%a"
    set "str=!str:%_strfind%=%_strinsert%!"
    set "str=!str:*]=!"
    >>%inputfile% echo(!str!
)
```

If by any chance your file might contain `!` it will not replicate them to file, then simply use this:

```
@echo off
set "inputfile=ip.txt"
set /p "_strfind=string to replace?"
set /p "_strinsert=replacement string?"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%inputfile%"') do (
    set "str=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "str=!str:%_strfind%=%_strinsert%!"
    call set "str=%%str:*]=%%"
    >>%inputfile% echo(!str!
    endlocal
)
```

Edit, as per your comment:

```
@echo off
set "inputfile=install.txt"
set /p "_strfind=string to replace? "
set /p "_strinsert=replacement string? "
set /p "_strfind2=enter Executable numeric value to replace? "
set /p "_strinsert2=enter the replacement value for executable? "
set "_strfind2=%_strfind2%.exe"
set "_strinsert2=%_strinsert2%.exe" 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%inputfile%"') do (
    set "str=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "str=!str:%_strfind%=%_strinsert%!"
    set "str=!str:%_strfind2%=%_strinsert2%!"
    call set "str=%%str:*]=%%"
    >>%inputfile% echo(!str!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Do you by any chance edit the script to change the values of both of the following: 

1. C:\Program Files\Java\userapp\fundays\jv10_85cl1\Prod

2. JAVAVarsiteSSV10_85fundays1.exe

to the value of 10_85cl1 and 10_85fundays1, i need to change the value of 1 at the end, but it changes the 1 at the beginning....eg: 10_85cl1 changes to 10_87cl2, but the 1 infront changes as well, eg: 20_85cl2, it needs to stay 10_85cl2

Comment: well, what are the conditions of the second replacement?

Comment: are these in the same file? Please show me what it looks like

Comment: JAVAVarsiteSSV10_85fundays1.exe

eg: here i need to change the 10_85fundays1 to 10_86fundays2 or 10_86fundays4

the 10 part infront needs to stay the same

Comment: so the 1 is before the .exe always?

Comment: the 1 at the end changes all the time the 1 infront of the 0 (10) needs to stay the same, lets say the 10 needs to stay the same

Comment: if i replace the 1, with the script, the 10 changes aswell

Comment: so just the last numeric value?

Comment: yes, the only numeric values that needs to change is the following:

10_85cl1 changes to 10_89cl5, depending on what needs to be put in

Comment: and JAVAVarsiteSSV10_85fundays1.exe changes to JAVAVarsiteSSV10_87fundays6.exe or to JAVAVarsiteSSV10_82fundays9.exe depending on what needs to be put in

Comment: Thank you i'll try quick

Comment: sure, let me know.